# why can't I build a dll via codelite-ide?

Tags: windows, dll

on windows, via codelite (compiler gcc), I wrote a simple program and wanted to build it into a dll.

After I built the project, no dll came out.
Then I ported the program to dev-c++, built it, dll came out successfully.

why codelite didn't work?
Because I chose gcc?

Answer (score 2):

If anyone else is having issues with creating/linking libraries with CodeLite on Windows, ensure that the output filename does not contain the .so extension.  By default, CodeLite on Windows uses the Unix shared object (.so) extension, so change it to dynamically linked library (.dll) in you project options.

<_<

Spent a very annoying three hours playing with configurations and puling my hair out as to why the linker (ld) could not find my compiled libraries.   Time for some much needed sleep...zzzz

Answer (score 1):

CodeLite use gcc/g++ as its compiler.
probably, its gcc/g++ compiler won't work as you expect on your winOS.
use [MingW](http://www.mingw.org/) or [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/), they will work as you expected if you stick to gcc/g++.